# Angular external templates in script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-template

When using templates, we'll probably host the application on a webserver else this gonna result in a cross origin error. So, I'm putting my templates in a script tag as follows:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
some text goes here
</script>
```

But is it possible to put the above in an external file. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
<script src="template.js" type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html"></script>
```

**Content of template.js**

```
some text goes here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent this error by opening your chrome browser with following flags.

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Open cmd and run above command.

**NOTE**

Make sure your browser is closed before you run above command.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is non-sense. You can't make every user to open their browser by *security-disabled* mode.

Comment: This is for testing your angular app in local. If you host it then there will be no issue like this.